# How to add shortcut to brightness-controller package?

Tags: brightness, shortcuts

I couldn't adjust my computer's brightness after I installed Ubuntu 16.04 with its default controller. Then, I downloaded `brightness-controller` package which is a great tool. It worked. Now I want to add shortcuts to this package's controllers for darkening and whitening. Which commands should I integrate with shortcuts?

[image]

Comment: Hi  Göktuğ Aşçı, posted.

Comment: Wait, you wanted the shortcuts to directly raise or lower brightness? The application does not provide any cli options. Even has no man page(!) .  Deleted my answer.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Are there any alternatives for this package which also provide options?

Comment: I will look into the code, see if I can fix something. Or write someting:)

Comment: Hi  Göktuğ Aşçı, I noticed I already wrote a script to be used with shortcuts, see the dupe link above. Both brightness-control and the linked dupe use simple xrandr brightness commands, functionality is exactly similar.